# How do I solve Attribute error in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I had written the following code in Google Colab. Earlier it was working fine but now it is showing attribute error('Page' has no attribute 'Rotation Matrix') at the convert line.

Content of Apollo 2019 file-

ORDINARY BUSINESS:

1. To consider and adopt:
   a.   the audited financial statement of the Company for the financial year ended March 31, 2019, the reports of the Board of
   Directors and Auditors thereon; and
   b.   the audited consolidated financial statement of the Company for the financial year ended March 31, 2019 and report of
   Auditors thereon.
2. To declare dividend of 3.25 per equity share, for the financial year ended March 31, 2019.
3. To appoint Mr.Robert Steinmetz (DIN: 00178792), who retires by rotation, and being eligible, offers himselfforre-appointment
   and in this regard to consider and if thought fit, to pass the following resolution as a Special Resolution:-
   “RESOLVED THAT pursuant to provisions of Section 152 and all other applicable provisions of the Companies Act, 2013
   and Regulation 17(1A) of SEBI (Listing Obligations & Disclosure Requirements) Regulations, 2015, and other applicable
   provisions, if any, (including any statutory modification(s) or re-enactment thereof, for the time being in force), consent of the
   Members of the Company be and is hereby accorded to re-appoint, Mr. Robert Steinmetz (DIN: 00178792), Director, aged 79
   years, who retires by rotation and being eligible offers himself for re-appointment, as a Director of the Company, liable to
   retire by rotation.”
4. To appoint a Director in place of Mr. Francesco Gori (DIN: 07413105), who retires by rotation, and being eligible, offers
   himself for re-appointment.

Please provide any solution if anyone knows.

```
!pip install python-docx
!pip install pdf2docx

from pdf2docx import Converter
from docx import Document

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

file_name='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/PDF files/Apollo 2019.pdf'
word_name='Apollo 2019.docx'

cv=Converter(file_name)
cv.convert(word_name)
cv.close()
```

## Element is a base class processing coordinates, so set rotation matrix globally

--> 279         Element.set_rotation_matrix(self.fitz_page.rotationMatrix)
280
281         return raw_layout

AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'rotationMatrix'

This is the error which I am getting.

Comment: What is contained in the files `Apollo 2019.pdf` and `Apollo 2019.txt`?

Comment: Apollo 2019.pdf contains text as well as charts and images and .txt file is what I created to store all the paragraphs which contains the required words

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. You need to make a reproducible example which includes the data and the smallest amount of code that will reproduce the problem. This ensures that contributors can check their code fixes the problem without wasting time.

Comment: I have shortened the code and added the error which I am getting

Comment: Include some data so that others have some chance of seeing the problem and then confirming a fix. Without data, it is impossible.

Comment: I have added the contents of the Apollo 2019 pdf file. Apollo 2019.txt is the file which will be created and it will contain the paragraphs containing the particular words mentioned in the list 'words'.

Comment: The trouble is that by copying the text of the PDF file into the question, it is no longer the PDF file that causes the problem. It would be better to host the PDF file somewhere and share a link.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fix, per se. But I went in and commented out the line 279 in the  RawPage.py file. After that, pdf2docx still executed properly and returned a file. Good luck

Comment: I tried that but it is still showing me the same error